# How to change 'Status Bar' colour in Flutter WEB? (After saving as a bookmark)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I can save my flutter web app on home screen as an bookmark icon. When I open it, the status bar color is black which looks very odd and does not appear to be an 'app like'.

How can I give the same color as my scaffold to the status bar?

My existing code is as follows:

```
...
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<CP>(
      create: (BuildContext content) => CP(),
      child: MaterialApp(
          title: 'App title',
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          theme: ThemeData(
            canvasColor: Colors.transparent,
            primarySwatch: white,
            //primaryColor: Colors.white
          ),
          routes: {
            ...
          },
          home: MainBody()),
    );
  }
}

class MainBody extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainBodyState createState() => _MainBodyState();
}

class _MainBodyState extends State<MainBody> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                  stops: [0.1, 1],
                  end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                  colors: [
                    Provider.of<CP>(context).primary,
                    Provider.of<CP>(context).secondary,
                  ],
                ), //Provider.of<CP>(context).fMainPageGradient
              ),
              child: SafeArea(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: <Widget>[
                  ....
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Just add this line in index.html to the `<head>` tag and replace "#000000" with the color you like.

```
<meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
```

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to change it dinamically according to the screen where I am?

Answer (score -2):

You can change the statusbar color with this

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    updateStatusBar();
    super.initState();
  }

  void updateStatusBar() {
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
      SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.amber),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks @Jaime but this doesn't work on flutter web. I checked.